# the first time / first time

Tags: phrase-meaning

As I understand it, the first version is more common, but I see in my grammar book the second one. Are they the same?

> I didn’t pass my driving test **the first time**.
>
> I didn’t pass my driving test **first time**.

Comment: It sounds like you're having an issue with when to use "the" and not. The first version is the only acceptable version in the US, at least.

Comment: The book was published by Cambridge University Press.

Comment: You'll need to ask a British English speaker, I'm afraid. One will probably show up soon.

Comment: His interlocutor said him: "I passed (it) first time." (not **the first time**)

Comment: Yes, 'first time' is perfectly acceptable in British English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternatives to "first time", you can use  "at/in (somewhat more rarely) the first attempt" or "on/at (far more rarely) the first try", the latter with the preposition "on" being [the most frequent usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+first+attempt%2Cin+the+first+attempt%2Cat+the+first+try%2Con+the+first+try&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20first%20attempt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20first%20attempt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20first%20try%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20first%20try%3B%2Cc0).